# how do I display the content of <p> in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="albumclass">
  <img width="100" height="100" data-assigned-id="9" src="/Content/images/fold.png">
  <p>15Sep2015</p>
</div>
```

The above code is generated dynamically through jQuery. After that I need to display the content of `<p>` ie., '`15Sep2015`' by clicking on the above image. How can I get this? I used the below code:

```
$('.album_inner').on('dblclick', '.albumclass img', function (e) {
  var txt = $(this).closest("p").text();
  alert(txt);
}
```

But that alerts nothing.It not possible to take content implicitly because a lot of similar div will be there.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i saw some spacing issues and just highlighted the specific thing which OP wants to get, while your edits don't suggests any improvement in it.

Comment: @Jai Sorry man. Will add your edits then. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) gets the parent. So use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [`.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/). I have used `.next()`:

```
$('.album_inner').on('dblclick', '.albumclass img', function (e) {
  var txt = $(this).next("p").text();
  alert(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go up to parent `div` and find `p` using `find()` :

```
$('.album_inner').on('dblclick', '.albumclass img', function (e) {
    var txt = $(this).closest("div").find('p').text();
    alert(txt);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As per structure you can get the target element directly with `.next()` then there is no need to go up to the parent then find the specific `p`. instead use `.siblings()`.

Comment: `.next()` is quicker than `.closest().find()`.

Comment: Yes that true @PraveenKumar thanks for your intervention but i don't know why _is not good_.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.albumclass').on('click', function(){
var p_text = $(this).children('p').text();
alert(p_text);
});
```

Comment: "on" event function use when element dynamic created. whenever click on "albumclass" class, i bind click event using on event function, then using $(this) which refer current object, get its children which should be p element and get its text and then alert. Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Why not try adding a class to the 'p' tag so that u can get the element by a class selector and see
`var text = $('.class').text();alert(text);`
or u may try 
`$(document.body).on('click','.class',function(){
});`